# Php cURL SCRIPT_URL

Tags: php, curl

I'm using cURL to get content of page from other site. When I open this page in my browser I have `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] = '/content/'`. 
But when I get this page with cURL i have `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] = '/content/index.php'`.

What request should I send to have same `SCRIPT_URL` as in browser?

Here is my class to get page:

```
<?php

class CurlReader implements IReader
{
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $_lastResponseHeaders = null;


/**
 * @param string $url
 * @param array $context
 * @return string
 */
public function read($url, array $context = null)
{
    $this->_lastResponseHeaders = null;
    $return = '';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array(&$this, 'readHeader'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');

    if (!empty($context['method'])) {
        if (strtolower($context['method']) == 'post') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        }
    }
    if (!empty($context['header'])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_map('trim', explode("\r", $context['header'])));
    }

    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        throw new ReaderException(curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $return;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getHeaders()
{
    return $this->_lastResponseHeaders;
}

/**
 * @param array $headers
 */
protected function readHeader($curl, $header)
{
    if (strpos($header, 'HTTP') !== false) {
        preg_match("/\d{3}/i", $header, $matches);
        $this->_lastResponseHeaders['Status'] = (int) $matches[0];
    } elseif (($pos = strpos($header, ':')) !== false) {
        $name = trim(substr($header, 0, $pos));
        $value = trim(substr($header, $pos + 1));
        $this->_lastResponseHeaders[$name] = $value;
    }
    return strlen($header);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]`

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php:

> 'SCRIPT_FILENAME'
>
> The absolute pathname of the currently executing script.

Comment: I can't change anything in site code. It uses $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] So I can only change request sending by cURL.

Comment: If it uses $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] then that is what it will return, the script URL, which may vary even for the same script depending on whether you specify the script explicitly or not in which case the web server chooses the script. I.e., /content/ the web server chooses index.php and executes that script, but the URL was just /content/. Are you specifying the script in the curl request?